# UK Short-Term Student Visa my Brother as a sponsor

Tags: visas, uk

i'm 20 years old, i am currently in my second year of study in the university in Algeria, i want to apply for General English courses in Liverpool school of English for 2 weeks so i need to apply for Short-term Student Visa but i have problem in financial requirements i need to seek advice from you please:

i have my brother who's working and has a bank account since 2014 he's working with state and private companies, selling to them electronic machines ( computers, printers ....) and also he's doing repair for them, they pay him through his bank account using bills and many papers, his bank account is professional (commercial) and last money he got was in December 2018(1500 pounds), now he'll receive amount of 2000 to 3000 pounds this week. now if he'll receive more funds and keep it in his bank account for 3 or 4 months, can i make him my sponsor on my visa application ? he will give me his bank statements, his bills, working documents.

***thanks for advance!***

Comment: You just posted this question earlier today. If you have additional information you should edit your question rather than reposting it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton yes i got many comments and guys who's helping me requested to post new question cause i got many things changed today

Comment: The additional questions you posted in comments under DJ Clayworth's answer were what you were told to post as separate questions. The primary question as asked was already answered. "Follow up" questions should be posted separately, including this case where your situation changed fundamentally.

Comment: @Steven Paul If you’ve not read this https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e# before, you’d find it useful to do so before posting a new question (or applying for your visa).

Comment: The change in the information about the brother's finances is so drastic that it would invalidate an existing answer to the existing question. I think a new question is justified here.